# Why Datetime.DayOfWeek is wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Consider this simple piece of code

```
var date = new DateTime(1307, 10, 13);
Console.WriteLine(date.DayOfWeek);
```

it outputs:

> Thursday

BUT,

[wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A8s_de_l'ordre_du_Temple) (french version) says that this date is a Friday :

> L'affaire débute au matin du **vendredi 13 octobre** 1307

Who is right?

My guess is that .Net doesn't take julien/gregorian calendar change into account.

Comment: Here's a site that says it was Thursday: https://www.dayoftheweek.org/?m=October&d=13&y=1307&go=Go.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: From that page: "The day of the week for October 13, 1307 under the old Julian calendar was Friday. Did you notice the difference with the Gregorian calendar?"

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, and the paragraph above that ends with "The day of the week was *Thursday*." I know all about the Julian/Gregorian change over and all that fun stuff (having done some research into George Washington's birthday). Just thought it was funny that this site said it was Thursday, not Sunday. Goes to show that you should take things you read on the internet with a big grain of salt.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I suspect the Sunday part was back when the OP was using a date in November...

Answer (score 16):

> my guess is that .Net doesn't take julien/gregorian calendar change into account

Indeed, as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) (emphasis mine):

> The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the **Gregorian calendar**.

Note that it couldn't take the Julian/Gregorian cut-over into account without more information, as that occurred on different dates in different places.

If you know you want to represent a date in the Julian calendar, I suggest you use the [`JulianCalendar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.juliancalendar?view=netframework-4.8) class.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using static System.FormattableString;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var julianCalendar = new JulianCalendar();
        var date = new DateTime(1307, 10, 13, julianCalendar);

        Console.WriteLine(Invariant($"Gregorian: {date:yyyy-MM-dd}"));
        Console.WriteLine(date.DayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Gregorian: 1307-10-21
Friday
```

Comment: I guess NodaTime does this a little differently - `new NodaTime.LocalDate(1307, 10, 13).DayOfWeek` gives Thursday.

Comment: @phuzi: No, it does it exactly the same way as .NET, defaulting to a proleptic Gregorian calendar. If you use `new LocalDate(1307, 10, 13, CalendarSystem.Julian).DayOfWeek` it prints Friday. The only difference is that the `LocalDate` retains its knowledge of the original calendar system, so it's still 1307-10-13 Julian, rather than 1307-10-21 (implicitly Gregorian) like the DateTime is.